# How to create a Scala executable jar file that is built with Maven, and has log4j included, using IntelliJ IDEA IDE

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, log4j, log4j2

Longtime Java developer trying to learn Scala(not with Spark). I wanted to build a basic Scala program that can be built using Maven and run as an executable jar. In addition, I wanted to go ahead and incorporate Log4j into it, so that I have a basic framework for building stand-alone jars. I had some trouble googling all the pieces I needed to do this, but I finally figured this out, so I wanted to post how to do this for others to use.

Comment: Thanks for this nice addition to SO. However please try to rephrase your question as an actual question. (The title is good.) Your personal backstory and motivation for posting this are not a question. Also "I have the solution, so here it is" does not go into the question. Since SO is a Q&A and not a forum, questions really should be only that: questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So, it turns out that I had to go with Log4j2(which I have never used) instead of Log4j(which I have used a lot). So, the basic environment I am using here is:

OS = Windows 10

IDE = IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.6 (Community Edition)

Java SDK = 1.8.0_111

Language = Scala 2.12.6

Build Tool = Maven

Steps:
1.  Go to File -> new project
Select a Maven project, and the **net.alchim31.maven:scala-archetype-simple archetype**:

[starting a new maven project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7IsQ.png)

Fill out group ID, artifact ID, and version on the next page:

[groupId, artifactId, and version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPhjI.png)

Then go with the defaults for the next 2 pages, and click "Finish"

2.) Import Maven dependencies: 
When the project first opens up, you should see a small popup in the bottom right corner, click on “Enable Auto-Import”:

[auto-import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0PZq.png)

3.) make a resources folder inside your project's main/scala folder
4.) go to File -> Project Structure:
In this window, you want to add this src/main/resources path as a resources folder, 
so in the project structure window, click modules, then resources, then rick click on 
your resources folder and select “resources”. 
Then you should see your folder on the right in purple as a resources folder, click “Apply”, then click “OK”:

[Project Structure window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA7XG.png)

5.) make a new package called "classes" inside your src/main/scala folder

6.) In the src/main/resources folder, make a new configuration file called log4j2.properties. This is for the log4j configuration.

7.) In this file, put the following information in it to configure a rolling log file called **msggen.log** that roles over every 10MB:

```
    name = PropertiesConfig
    appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
    appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
    appender.rolling.fileName = /home/ubuntu/logs/msggen/msggen.log
    appender.rolling.filePattern = /home/ubuntu/logs/msggen/msggen.%d{dd-MMM}.log.gz
    appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
    appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
    appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
    appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
    appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
    appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
    appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

    logger.rolling.name = msgGenLog
    logger.rolling.level = debug
    logger.rolling.additivity = false
    logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

8.) In your pom.xml, you need to add the log4j2 dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

9.) You also want to add build plugins for when you want to generate the executable jar.
Inside the **build** and **plugins** tags, add the following plugin tags(change the **finalName** tag to what you want your jar name to be):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>msggen</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.scala.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

10.) In your **src/main/scala/classes** folder that you made earlier, make a Scala object called **LogUtil.scala**, with the following code:

```
package classes

import org.apache.logging.log4j._

object LogUtil {

  val msggenLogger:Logger = LogManager.getLogger("msgGenLog");

  def msggenLoggerDEBUG(message: String): Unit = {
    this.msggenLogger.debug(message)
  }
}
```

11.) change your **App.scala** object to invoke your logger, here’s my code:

```
package com.scala

import classes.LogUtil
/**
  * @author ${user.name}
  */
object App {

  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    LogUtil.msggenLoggerDEBUG("Hi there!");
  }
}
```

12.) right click on the **App.scala** object and select “Run ‘App’” to test that the log file gets made and populated(set the config property **appender.rolling.fileName** to set where you want the log file to be created):

[test log message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmOZT.png)

**To Build the JAR file:**

1.) Go to File -> project structure again, and select the “Artifacts” tag on the left, then click the “+” button, then JAR -> from modules with dependencies:

[project structure for artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDX2V.png)

2.) In the “create JAR from modules” window, select your **App.scala** class as the main class, and make sure to specify the **src/main/resources** folder to where you want your manifest file to be made in(change it from **src/main/scala**):

[create jar from modules window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JleOc.png)

3.) Click OK and make a note of the "Output Directory" field which tells you where your jar is going to be after it is made.

4.) Click “Apply” and then “OK”.

5.) In the main window, go to “Build” -> Build Artifacts -> then in the little window that pops up, select “build” again

6.) Now in the Output Directory path noted earlier, you should see your jar file.

7.) I’m on Windows, so open a command line and go to the location where your jar is, and run it by typing

**Java -jar msggen.jar**

8.) go to your log file again to verify that your test message was logged:

[log file with 2nd message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAeXF.png)

So, now you should have a basic framework for a Scala application with Maven and Log4j2 integration within it.

Here is my full pom.xml for reference:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.scala</groupId>
  <artifactId>msggen</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
  <description>My wonderfull scala app</description>
  <inceptionYear>2018</inceptionYear>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>My License</name>
      <url>http://....</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.12.6</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.12</scala.compat.version>
    <spec2.version>4.2.0</spec2.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.12</artifactId>
          <version>11.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.11.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.11.0</version>
      </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spec2.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-junit_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spec2.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <args>
                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
              </args>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Tests will be run with scalatest-maven-plugin instead -->
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
          <junitxml>.</junitxml>
          <filereports>TestSuiteReport.txt</filereports>
          <!-- Comma separated list of JUnit test class names to execute -->
          <jUnitClasses>samples.AppTest</jUnitClasses>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```